# SQL query to get each EID's & JOINING_DT corresponding records in tab2 which are just previous, equal date and all greater date rows from tab2

Tags: sql, sap-iq

[image]tab1:

```
EID    JOINING_DT
---------
1     04/04/2018
2     06/06/2018
3     04/04/2018
4     03/03/2018
```

tab2:

```
EID  JOINING_DT  INFO
-------------------
1   01/01/2018   x
1   02/02/2018   x
1   03/03/2018   x
1   04/04/2018   x
1   05/05/2018   x
2   01/01/2018   x
2   05/05/2018   x
2   07/07/2018   x
3   02/02/2018   x
4   03/03/2018   x
```

By using above 2 tables i want to get t1.id = t2.d and date of t1 should be just prior, equal and all greater date. like below
Result:

```
EID  JOINING_DT  INFO
-------------------
1   03/03/2018   x
1   04/04/2018   x
2   01/01/2018   x
2   05/05/2018   x
2   07/07/2018   x
3   02/02/2018   x
4   03/03/2018   x
```

Note: Please consider the solution should be high performance with high volume of data

Comment: Please format your data so that it is readable.  Remove the images and instead include _text_.  And also tell us which database you are using.  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: first of all name your columns correctly what the hell you have in tables structure multiple same columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you were looking for

```
      select id, date,
       value from
       table1 t1 join
       table2 t2 on 
        (  t1.id =t2.id )
         and
         (abs(t2.date-t1.date) =1
         or 
          t1.date=t2.date)
```